# What is Microsoft OSLO?

Tags: oslo

Is it a DSL generation tool or natural query language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

”Oslo” is the codename for Microsoft’s forthcoming modeling platform. Modeling is used across a wide range of domains and allows more people to participate in application design and allows developers to write applications at a much higher level of abstraction. “Oslo” consists of:

- A tool that helps people define and interact with models in a rich
  and visual manner
- A language that helps people create and use textual
  domain-specific languages and data
  models
- A relational repository that makes models available to both tools
  and platform components

[More Information](http://www.microsoft.com/soa/products/oslo.aspx)

Also see: [OSLO FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd129873.aspx)